# Is it okay to use `require('babel/register);` in production?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

It *should not* use `babel-node` in production according to the official document of Babel. Some said you can use `babel/register` instead of `babel-node` if you don't want to compile your [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) code into [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009) before running. But doesn't `babel-node` use `babel/register` internally? What is the difference between `babel-node` and  `require('babel/register');`. Is it okay using `require('babel/register');` in production?

Comment: `babel-node` implements its own CLI interface, so it does much more than requiring `'babel/register'`.

Comment: As for you question, a lot of people do it (including myself), but I'm still looking forward to see some good reasoning whether it's a good or bad practice.

Comment: Is no one reading tag descriptions? `babel` is for questions for a Python library with said name.

Comment: I think the only drawback is that at the first request that hit the server, babel will transform and re-compile all the code and this will take some more time than normal. But, as said this will happen ONLY for the first request that hit the server (this case usually occurs after a new build of the code – i.e. after deploying a new feature), as code will be cached for subsequent requests, so I see no real issue in using it in production.

Comment: I've been wondering this myself too; I noticed that the official babel example doesn't - https://github.com/babel/example-node-server

Answer (score 9):

The [Babel Handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook) (linked from [babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/)) says that it's bad practice to use `babel-register` in production ([see babel-register user guide](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/user-handbook.md#toc-babel-register)):

> Note that this is not meant for production use. It's considered bad practice to deploy code that gets compiled this way. It is far better to compile ahead of time before deploying. However this works quite well for build scripts or other things that you run locally.

So it seems the suggested way is to compile before running using the `babel` command from the `babel-cli` package.

This also fits in with the [npm advice](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies) on using transpilers. (That advice is given for authoring npm packages, but applies in this case too).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to do it is to build it (`babel src -d dist`) and serve the transpiled version. This is what I'm currently doing as it feels safer, though I'm still having to import `babel-polyfill` in my startup file for the regenerator runtime to work. Without it I receive the `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

> server.js

```
'use strict'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
  require('babel-register')

require('babel-polyfill')
var log = require('nlogger').logger(module)
var app = require('express')()

var cfg = require('./config')
var db  = require('./db')


db.once('open', function () {
  log.info('MongoDB connected.')
})

db.on('close', function () {
  log.info('MongoDB closed.')
})

db.on('error', function (err) {
  log.error('MongoDB connection error:', err)
})

require('./middleware/express')(app)

var server = app.listen(cfg.port, function () {
  log.info('Server listening on port ', cfg.port)
})

// Start socket.io & bring in routes
var io = require('./io')(server)
require('./router')(app, io)


server.on('close', function () {
  log.info('Server connection closed.')
})


module.exports = server
```